# Disabling paste from clipboard to flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I have set  `enableInteractiveSelection: false,` for my text field in flutter App which it disabled the `select All, copy,paste` option for that text field. but in my app its allowing me to paste values from clipboard. I want  to stop that to.

[image]

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: its google keyboard, its not pasting the contents its kinda rewriting the text on text editor

Comment: @SohelMahmud, if I clicked on the Clipboard text its gets inserted into my text field, I dont want to allow paste thing for the text box

Comment: Actually you cannot tap on this type of detection. Google keyboard sends the charters stream as if user has typed those. Its not clipboard thing after all its Google Keyboard.

Comment: Have you found any solution for the above problem?